Choosing right payment method for using in mobile app
The mobile app allows you to post products , and you should buy a package to have access to posting, (for example you are buying package which allows you to post 10 products and etc.) which payment method is allowed for that? Can I go with some third party payment for example Apple Pay + Stripe or I must use in app purchase for that?

in app purchase is required because the service (posting product listings) is delivered in the app.  Payment for physical products themselves cannot be via in app purchase.

Digital goods/services require Apple IAP. other than that if the goods are physical then you can use 3rd party payment gateways.
